# What's the best way to draw statistic charts?

Tags: android, charts

I need to draw statistics charts about the information saved in the SQL Database, but I don't know if it's good idea to draw it "manually" using Canvas.
I've seen packages like aChartEngine and ChartPlot, but these are not as customizable as I want.
I've thought to use OpenGL too, but I'm not sure all phones can support it, althought it's a simple operation.

What's the best way to do it? Performance is essential for me, my application is designed to be used in low-range mobile phones too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at JIT or D3?  I've used them in the past for similar problems and found them to be very responsive on most mobile broswers:

http://philogb.github.com/jit/

http://d3js.org/

Comment: Thanks! Philogb's JIT is perfect for me! Do you know any tutorial for implement it in android? Thanks again!

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  I used it for websites that were targeted for mobile devices.  JFreeChart, as described below, should be embeddable into an Android app though.

Answer (score 2):

JFreeChart has android libs.

http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/

http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/index.html

I think thats one of the better ways. You could draw everything yourself but that would probably give you more problems later.